# How do install and work with github codes for next gen sequencing data analysis?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

From the `VIP` [`README.md`](https://github.com/keylabivdc/VIP/blob/master/README.md) file:

## Installation

The steps to install VIP on a machine are as follows:

```
> git clone https://github.com/keylabivdc/VIP

> cd VIP

> cd installer

> chmod 755 *

> sudo sh dependency_installer.sh

> sudo sh db_installer.sh -r [PATH]/[TO]/[DATABASE]
```

**I was able to do up to this point and I don't know how to do rest of the steps.**

## Usage

```
Create default config file.
    VIP.sh -z -i <NGSfile> -p <454/iontor/illumina> -f <fastq/fasta/bam/sam> -r <reference_path>

    Please do not include any path information for the NGS file.

    For example, Good for VIP.sh -z -i test.fq
                 Bad for VIP.sh -z -i [PATH]/test.fq

Run VIP with the config file:
    VIP.sh -c <configfile> -i <NGSfile>

Run VIP with verification mode
    VIP.sh -i <NGSfile> -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a *really* roundabout way to run a program, but doable.

You need to write a config file in the format they specify, which seems to just be the command you want to run. So for example:

**config.txt**

```
VIP.sh -z -i <name_of_NGSfile> -p <454/iontor/illumina> -f <fastq/fasta/bam/sam> -r /path/to/your/reference/genome
```

Where `-p` is the sequencing machine used (454, Ion Torrent, your standard Illumina runs), `-f` is the input file format, and `-r` is (presumably) the reference genome to be used in FASTA format.

You then run the program with:

```
VIP.sh -c <configfile> -i <NGSfile>
```

where `-c` is the path to your config file and `-i` is the path to your NGSfile.

The confusing part is that it doesn't seem to want the path to the input file in your config file, just a name for it. I think this should work though.